# Don't know why my method is not being called?

Tags: java, methods, double

I'm having trouble trying to pull the method amount back to the original main to display the amount that was calculated in the CalculateRoomCost method. I think I am going at the right approach, but I am new to methods so please help explain what I am doing wrong.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Problem {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome to Likuliku Lagoon Resort - Malolo Island, Fiji.");
        

        int nightsTotal = calculateRoomCost( int nights);

        System.out.println("The cost will be: " + nightsTotal);
    }

    public static double calculateRoomCost(int nights) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int nightsTotal;

        System.out.println("1 : Standard Room no view $100/night");
        System.out.println("2 : Luxury Room with view $200/night");
        System.out.println("3 : Luxury Room with Balcony $300/night");
        System.out.print("Please enter your choice: ");
        nights = input.nextInt();

        if (nights == 1)
            nightsTotal = 100;
        else if (nights == 2)
            nightsTotal = 200;
        else
            nightsTotal = 300;


        return nightsTotal;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your program has three problems,

- You need to input 'nights' in a variable and pass them to the function
- You don't need to provide a type in the function call. Simply give a variable name to the function as parameters.
- You need to return nightsTotal * night;

Also, the return type must be same as the variable you are using to store the returned value. You have double as return but you are storing it in an integer variable. This will cause data loss because integers can't store fractional parts.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Problem {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome to Likuliku Lagoon Resort - Malolo Island, Fiji.");
        
        System.out.println("Enter nights to stay.");
        int nights = input.nextInt();
        int nightsTotal = calculateRoomCost( nights);

        System.out.println("The cost will be: " + nightsTotal);
    }


    public static int calculateRoomCost(int nights) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int nightsTotal;
        int perNight;

        System.out.println("1 : Standard Room no view $100/night");
        System.out.println("2 : Luxury Room with view $200/night");
        System.out.println("3 : Luxury Room with Balcony $300/night");
        System.out.print("Please enter your choice: ");
        nights = input.nextInt();

        if (nights == 1)
            perNight = 100;
        else if (nights == 2)
            perNight = 200;
        else
            perNight = 300;
        
        nightsTotal = perNight * nights;

        return nightsTotal;
    }
}

/*output
Welcome to Likuliku Lagoon Resort - Malolo Island, Fiji.
Enter nights to stay.
3
1 : Standard Room no view $100/night
2 : Luxury Room with view $200/night
3 : Luxury Room with Balcony $300/night
Please enter your choice: 2
The cost will be: 400
*/
```

Comment: Also note that passing the argument to `calculateRoomCost` is useless because it gets overwritten before it is even used. And that the parameter is incorrectly named as in the end it doesn't represent the number of nights to be spent at the hotel, but the type of room the user books.