# How to pull the information from the methods that the user entered and display them to the user in the main

Tags: java, loops, methods

I cannot figure out how to display the total results from the methods to the user. I also could not figure out how to make it loop for each amount of guests the user inputs.

I have to use the methods that are provided for this problem too. I also have a preview of what it should look like down below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Problem {
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double sum = 0;

        //display welcome
        System.out.println("Welcome to Likuliku Lagoon Resort - Malolo Island, Fiji.\n");

        System.out.println("Please enter number of guests: ");
        int guests = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("How many nights will you be staying? ");
        int GuestNights = input.nextInt();

        double loop = getActivitiesCost();


        while (loop != 6) {

            sum = sum + calculateRoomCost() + calculateMealPlan();

            loop = getActivitiesCost();
            System.out.println();
        }//end while loop



        }
        public static double calculateRoomCost (int nights){
            System.out.println("1: Standard Room no view $100/night");
            System.out.println("2: Luxury Room with view $200/night");
            System.out.println("3: Luxury Room with Balcony $300/night");
            System.out.print("Please enter your choice: ");
            int cost = input.nextInt();

            if (nights == 1)
                return cost * 100.00;
            else if (nights == 2)
                return cost * 200.00;
            else  if (nights == 3)
                return cost * 300.00;

            return cost;
        }

        public static double calculateMealPlan ( int nights){
            System.out.println("1: Lunch & Dinner only $65");
            System.out.println("2: 3-Meals a day $150");
            System.out.println("3: 3-Meals a day with drinks $225");
            System.out.println("4: No meal plan $0");
            System.out.print("Please enter your choice: ");
            int x = input.nextInt();

            if (nights == 1)
                return x * 65.00;
            else if (nights == 2)
                return x * 150.00;
            else if (nights == 3)
                return x * 225.00;
            else if (nights == 4)
                return 0;

            return nights;
        }

        public static double getActivitiesCost () {
            System.out.println("Choose from these activities");
            System.out.println("1: Scuba Adventure $300");
            System.out.println("2: Island Shopping Hop $100");
            System.out.println("3: Paddle Boarding $125");
            System.out.println("4: Deep Sea Fishing $500");
            System.out.println("5: Beach Sitting $0");
            System.out.println("6: That's all--Done!");
            System.out.print("Please enter your choice: ");
            int loop = input.nextInt();
            if (loop == 1)
                return loop * 300.00;
            else if (loop == 2)
                return loop * 100.00;
            else if (loop == 3)
                return loop * 125.00;
            else if (loop == 4)
                return loop * 500.00;
            else if (loop == 5)
                return 0;
            return loop;
        }


    }//end class
```

Input/output:

```
Welcome to Likuliku Lagoon Resort - Malolo Island, Fiji.
Please enter number of guests: 2
How many nights will you be staying? 2
Start entering details for guest #1
1 : Standard Room no view $100/night
2 : Luxury Room with view $200/night
3 : Luxury Room with Balcony $300/night
Please enter your choice: 1
1 : Lunch & Dinner only $65
2 : 3-Meals a day $150
3 : 3-Meals a day with drinks $225
4 : No meal plan $0
Please enter your choice: 2
Choose from these activities
1 : Scuba Adventure $300
2 : Island Shopping Hop $100
3 : Paddle Boarding $125
4 : Deep Sea Fishing $500
5 : Beach Sitting $0
6 : That's all--Done!
Enter your choice: 1
Choose from these activities
1 : Scuba Adventure $300
2 : Island Shopping Hop $100
3 : Paddle Boarding $125
4 : Deep Sea Fishing $500
5 : Beach Sitting $0
6 : That's all--Done!
Enter your choice: 6
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Start entering details for guest #2
1 : Standard Room no view $100/night
2 : Luxury Room with view $200/night
3 : Luxury Room with Balcony $300/night
Please enter your choice: 2
1 : Lunch & Dinner only $65
2 : 3-Meals a day $150
3 : 3-Meals a day with drinks $225
4 : No meal plan $0
Please enter your choice: 2
Choose from these activities
1 : Scuba Adventure $300
2 : Island Shopping Hop $100
3 : Paddle Boarding $125
4 : Deep Sea Fishing $500
5 : Beach Sitting $0
6 : That's all--Done!
Enter your choice: 5
Choose from these activities
1 : Scuba Adventure $300
2 : Island Shopping Hop $100
3 : Paddle Boarding $125
4 : Deep Sea Fishing $500
5 : Beach Sitting $0
6 : That's all--Done!
Enter your choice: 6
The total cost estimate $1500.00
The average nightly cost person is $375.
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question, but from what i can see in the code i recommend reading: [The Java Tutorials - Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html), because you defined methods that require you to pass arguments into them but then try to call them without arguments, which cannot work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Don't know why my method is not being called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74331506/dont-know-why-my-method-is-not-being-called)

Comment: 3rd time you posted this…

Answer (score 0):

### First of all, in this answer, efforts and time were spent to solve the question (which is a bit complex) and to explain the solutions to the problems that the questioner raised in a clear way. Therefore, I would like anyone who is helped by this answer to raise my points by clicking on the upper arrow next to my answer.

I will briefly list the answers to the questions in order to make it easier for those who look at the problem - so that they don't have to understand all the code that the questioner wrote, and also write explanatory notes in the code for everything I wrote:

1. "How to pull the information from the methods that the user entered and display them to the user in the main":
   The key answer is: by a variable or an array (sometimes their definition should be global, for example if you are summarizing data from several functions and not by returning the data to the summarizing function). Think about what is true for the problem you are solving
   Specific to the questioner's problem: he saved the data in the sum variable and only had to present it to the user (note in a certain place he forgot to sum something - detailed in the code).
2. "how to make it loop for each amount of guests the user inputs" - by making a for loop of the length of the number of guests and writing there the code and the functions you want to be executed past each one (as you see in the code) .
   The next function is the main function.

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    double sum = 0;

    System.out.println("Welcome to Likuliku Lagoon Resort - Malolo Island, Fiji.\n");

    System.out.println("Please enter number of guests: ");
    int guests = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("How many nights will you be staying? ");
    int GuestNights = input.nextInt();

    //the for loop that I added ְְThis answers your question:
    //"How to make it loop for whatever amount of guests the user enters."
    for (int i = 0; i < guests; i++) {
        System.out.println("Start entering details for guest #" + (i + 1));

        //Because you called the function as initialization, wrong lines were printed and unnecessary calculation,
        // so I changed it to a value of 0 which is different from 6 and the loop will be executed once cleanly
        double loop = 0;

        sum = sum + calculateRoomCost(GuestNights) + calculateMealPlan(GuestNights);
        while (loop != 6) {
            loop = getActivitiesCost();

            //sum= stores the total amount, so you also need to add the calculation returned from the function getActivitiesCost()
            //The possible problem is that the result of this function is also used to stop the wile loop (that's why you were probably afraid to add this line)
            //The solution is to make a condition that only if the result is different from 6 (which is the stopping condition that could spoil the calculation) then add the result to the sum
            if (loop != 6)
                sum += loop;
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("------------------------------");
    }

    //The answer to your question how to display the total results from the methods to the user:
    //print the sum which, as mentioned, saves the entire requested calculation
    System.out.println("the total cost estimate: " + sum + "$");
    System.out.println("The average nightly cost person is: " + (sum / guests / GuestNights) + "$");
}
```

Comment: I only wrote the main function because it was the only one I made changes to. The rest of the functions remained the same